# Android layout height is not setting properly

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my layout xml (part of xml) which is area of concern

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rating"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/address"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="@color/timestamp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/news_feed_item_timestamp"
                android:width="0dip"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

As shown in the code I am displaying a rating inside circular view with corner radius as 30dp and then address next to it.
My problem is while circular text view is showing properly, address when wrapped is not showing clearly all lines.

When i tried to change layout_height of TextView to

```
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

address is showing properly however shape of the circle is gone.
Please help

Update:
Adding screenshot of what I am getting 
[image: With android:layout_height="wrap_content"]

[image: With android:layout_height="match_parent"]

I want combination of 2, perfect circle with complete text view

Comment: can you provide Images for **what you are getting** and **what you want**.

Comment: @Meet Added image

Comment: use wrap_content, whenever you are using weight attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem would be solved if you change the height of the textview to wrap_content...

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have set properly your weight information. The first textview doesn't have any weight constraint.

To have your 2 textviews side by side do this:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rating"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/address"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/timestamp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/news_feed_item_timestamp"
            android:width="0dip"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

With this code, the to textview have the same size. To modify this, play with weight value.

Comment: Tried this but no luck. My text views are side by side as shown in the image, problem is height

Answer (score 0):

I got your problem.

I think you should have to wrap your first `TextView` inside any container (say `LinearLayout`) like this:

### Instead of this:

```
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/rating"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@drawable/circle"
  android:padding="10dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
  android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
```

### Try this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/rating"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@drawable/circle"
      android:padding="10dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
      android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This Code in drawable Circle for making Circular Background.
`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid
        android:color="#ffffff"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/red_app" />
</shape>`
```

I Have Solved This type of Problem by this code

```
  <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="45dp"
                        android:layout_height="45dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/circle">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvidle_count"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:text="0"
                            android:textColor="@color/black_app"
                            android:textSize="18sp" />

                    </RelativeLayout>
```